# TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I save my model in a HD5F file as follows:

```
model.save('my_model1.h5')
```

Whenever I try to load my model in my local machine using:

```
new_model = keras.models.load_model('my_model.h5')
```

I got next error:

> TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

How to resolve it?